# Create fixed length non-repeating permutation of larger set

Tags: php, permutation

I know this topic is much discussed but I can't seem to find any implementation that fits my needs.

I have the following set of characters:

> a b c d e f g h

I want to get all possible permutations or combinations (non repeating), **but on a limited (variable) set of characters**, meaning if I input the characters and the number `2`, the results should look like

```
ab ba ac ca ad da ae ea af fa ag ga ah ha
bc cb bd db be eb bf fb bg gb bh hb
cd dc ce ec cf fc cg gc ch hc
de ed df fd dg gd dh hd
ef fe eg ge eh he
fg gf fh hf
gh hg
```

I hope you understand where I'm going with this. I currently have an implementation that gives me the permutations of **all** characters, but I can't wrap my head around how to implement a **limited space** for those permutations:

```
public function getPermutations($letters) {
    if (strlen($letters) < 2) {
        return array($letters);
    }

    $permutations = array();
    $tail = substr($letters, 1);

    foreach ($this->getPermutations($tail) as $permutation) {
        $length = strlen($permutation);

        for ($i = 0; $i <= $length; $i++) {
            $permutations[] = substr($permutation, 0, $i) . $letters[0] . substr($permutation, $i);
        }
    }

    return $permutations;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only need one element at a time, you can save on memory by generating each element individually.

If we wanted to generate a random string in your set of expected outputs, we could use this algorithm:

```
Given a set of characters S, and a desired output length K:
  While the output has less than K characters:
    Pick a random number P between 1 and |S|.
    Append the P'th character to the output.
    Remove the P'th character from S.
```

where `|S|` is the current number of elements in S.

We can actually encode this sequence of choices into an integer. One way to do that is to change the algorithm as such:

```
Given a set of characters S, and a desired output length K:
  Let I = 0.
  While the output has less than K characters:
    I = I * (|S| + 1).
    Pick a random number P between 1 and the number of elements in S.
    I = I + P.
    Append the P'th character to the output.
    Remove the P'th character from S.
```

After running this algorithm, the value `I` will uniquely encode this particular sequence of choices. It basically encodes this as a [mixed-radix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_radix) number; one digit uses base N, the next uses N-1, and so on until the last digit which is base N-K+1 (N being the number of letters in the input).

Naturally, we can also decode this again, and in PHP, that would be something like this:

```
// Returns the total number of $count-length strings generatable from $letters.
function getPermCount($letters, $count)
{
  $result = 1;
  // k characters from a set of n has n!/(n-k)! possible combinations
  for($i = strlen($letters) - $count + 1; $i <= strlen($letters); $i++) {
    $result *= $i;
  }
  return $result;
}

// Decodes $index to a $count-length string from $letters, no repeat chars.
function getPerm($letters, $count, $index)
{
  $result = '';
  for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
  {
    $pos = $index % strlen($letters);
    $result .= $letters[$pos];
    $index = ($index-$pos)/strlen($letters);
    $letters = substr($letters, 0, $pos) . substr($letters, $pos+1);
  }
  return $result;
}
```

(Note that for simplicity, this particular decoding algorithm does not correspond exactly to the encoding algorithm I previously described, but maintains the desirable property of a given `$index` mapping to a unique result.)

To use this code, you would do something like this:

```
$letters = 'abcd';
echo '2 letters from 4:<br>';
for($i = 0; $i < getPermCount($letters, 2); $i++)
  echo getPerm($letters, 2, $i).'<br>';

echo '<br>3 letters from 4:<br>';
for($i = 0; $i < getPermCount($letters, 3); $i++)
  echo getPerm($letters, 3, $i).'<br>';
?>
```

Comment: And how will he save on memory? He need "all possible permutations or combinations". Difference in algorithm will not make array of results smaller.

Comment: @UAWDT: When you're dealing with permutations, you *usually* just need to iterate over them and process them individually. You don't need to store them all in a big array in order to do that - you can generate each element as you need it, and throw it away when you're done with it. In other words, it's the difference between `$perms = getPerms(); foreach ($perms as $perm)` and `for ($i=0;$i<getPermCount(...);$i++) $perm = getPerm($i);`.

Comment: After two days I found a perfect answer

Answer (score 2):

```
$strings = get_perm( range('a', 'h'), 4 );

function get_perm( $a, $c, $step = 0, $ch = array(), $result = array() ){
    if( $c == 1 ){ //if we have last symbol in chain
        for( $k = 0; $k < count( $a ); $k++ ){
            if( @in_array( $k, $ch ) ) continue; // if $k exist in array we already have such symbol in string
            $tmp = '';

            foreach( $ch as $c ) $tmp .= $a[$c]; // concat chain of previous symbols
            $result[] = $tmp . $a[$k]; // and adding current + saving to our array to return
        }
    }else{
        for( $i = 0; $i < count( $a ); $i++ ){
            if( @in_array( $i, $ch ) ) continue;
            $ch[$step] = $i; // saving current symbol for 2 things: check if that this symbol don't duplicate later and to know what symbols and in what order need to be saved
            get_perm( $a, $c-1, $step+1, $ch, &$result ); 
            // recursion, 
            // decrementing amount of symbols left to create string, 
            // incrementing step to correctly save array or already used symbols, 
            // $ch - array of already used symbols, 
            // &$result - pointer to result array
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

**NOTICE**

a-h with 6 symbols = 20k values in array
a-z with 4 symbols = 358799 values in array
So a-z with 10 symbols will die for sure =) It will require too much memory.
You need to try to save output to file or database if you would need big amount of values. Or extend memory limit to php but not sure if this is best way.

Comment: This is idea, but you can extend it to  reach your goal =) if you will need more help on this just ask =)

Comment: I miss that you have values like ba, ca etc. For this just change `for( $i = $step` to `for( $i = 0`

Comment: Seems to work fine for 2 characters, but when I set `$c = 3`, I get alternating 3 and 2 letter combinations, e.g. `abc, ab, acd, ac, ade, ad,...`

Comment: check my code again please. It was edited and yeah, there was such problem

Comment: I see it on 4. Wait few minutes. Need to think =)

Comment: Any luck on getting that fixed? To be honest, I tried to step through your algorithm but don't really have a clue what's going on in there :D

Comment: lol. I'll finish with it today and update answer. I'll add comments

Comment: @FlorianPeschka Code is updated. Now it is working correctly for any amount =)